# Calling a Constructor Method in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a class that makes car objects. It has two instance variables: Make and Color. I am having an issue calling this method within the workspace (noted below)

Class Method -Constructor

```
make: aMake color: aColor
    "Creates a new car object, sets its instance variables by the arguments"
    |car|
    car := self new.
    car setMake: aMake setColor: aColor. "accessor method below"
    ^car
```

Accessor Method

```
setMake: make setColor: color
    "sets the instance variables"
    Make := make.
    Color := color.
```

Workspace (calling code)

```
|car|
car := Car make: 'toyota' color: 'red'
```

I get 'Message Not Understood' when calling this line. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything looks alright. The likely gotcha would be that your "constructor" (which would more likely be called an "instance creation message" in Smalltalk) needs to be implemented on the class side, and you may have done so on the instance side. Conversely, your set... must be on the instance side. Which message is not understood (error details always help)? It should say in the debugger and that would help clarify.

Comment: My issue was with the IDE

Answer (score 0):

I notice two additional issues with your code:

- in smalltalk we don't use 'set' for setters
- the instance variables have a lowercase initial.

So the initializer would be

```
make: aMake color: aColor
   "sets the instance variables"
    make := aMake.
    color := aColor.
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the `set` comment. It's true you don't see that many of them. But they do exist. `setValue:` for instance. My stock Pharo image has 1199 methods that start with 'set' in it.

Comment: #setX:y: (notice set is only at the beginning) IIRC is one of the patterns from Best Practices. Usually I'm too lazy and just use accessors

Answer (score 0):

The reference book for doing all of these things right is:

[http://www.amazon.com/Smalltalk-Best-Practice-Patterns-Kent/dp/013476904X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013476904X)

Click on the "Look Inside" picture and you'll be able to get to the table of contents and the constructor method receipe.

I obviously can't copy the thing here, so here is a small extract picture.

[image: Constructor Method]